# map is overlapping on the drawer in flutter. how to fix this?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I tried to attach Google Maps using MapView and then I tried to attach the drawer in my appbar but when I open the drawer, the map overlaps the drawer and I can't see the items of drawer. How can I fix this?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//  var mq = MediaQuery.of(context);
  return new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Map view example"),
      ),
     body:  new Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: <Widget>[
           new Container(
             height: 250.0,
             child: new Stack(
               children: <Widget>[
                 new Center(
                     child: new Container(
                       child: new Center(
                         heightFactor: 200.0,
                         widthFactor: 200.0,
                         child: showMap(),
                       ),
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                     )),

               ],
             ),
           ),
           new Container(
             padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
             child: new Text(
               "Tap the map to interact",
               style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
             ),
           ),

         ],
       ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new Text("Drawer"),
      ),
     ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Map is using a NativeView which is always shown top-most. There was a change recently that might fix that. I think you could try the plugin from the GitHub repo using a Git dependency.